# Connect to mysql database with local Ip address - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I want to connect to database with ip address instead of local host, but when I write IP Address (another PC in LAN), it shows me error of permission denied.My connection array is as follows:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '192.168.1.122';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '123456';
$db['default']['database'] = 'test_db';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

result is:

> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Permission denied
>       Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

I am using CentOS 7 and tried connection with telnet and it is working fine there.

Comment: Are you allowed to access the MySQL port via Firewall? Seems like you have been blocked. Please check that you have access and control over the MySQL ports in your Firewall.

Comment: That IP is the number t your router. Maybe this is why it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you haven't the permission to log as root from a host different from localhost. You can find info [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/default-privileges.html).

You can grant permissions to root this way:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mysql root password';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found the solution to be that Apache was not set to allow remote connections.

You can run this to check:

```
getsebool -a | grep httpd_can_network
```

I ran the following to fix the issue:

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

*Source:*

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/centos-7-warning-mysqli_connect-hy000-2002-permission-denied-in
- https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/error-mysqli_connect-hy000-2002-permission-denied-4175588599/